# Selenium 2 window switching: Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Hi basically I am trying to switch to a popup window then press a
button on that popup window but from somereaon I am getting erros.

Here is an example of the webpage

http://i42.photobucket.com/albums/e326/limpep/example.png

and here is my code

```
 for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                                 driver.switchTo().window(handle);

                               }


                       WebElement clicksa  =
driver.findElement(By.id("ButtonCancle"));
                           clicksa.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
                           driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Errers that i am getting

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element by id using "Accept Address" (7)
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_21'
Driver info: driver.version: ie
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.ErrorHandler.verifyErrorCode(ErrorHandler.java:38)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.Finder.handleErrorCode(Finder.java:252)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.Finder.findElementById(Finder.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$1.findElement(By.java:66)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.Finder.findElement(Finder.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.findElement(InternetExplorerDriver.java:297)
    at com.capscanWebServers.CRMTesting$2.actionPerformed(CRMTesting.java:112)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Kind Regards

Comment: whats the error you are getting? "I am getting errors" doesn't explain what's gone wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are probably not switching to the correct window. You are iterating all windows and switching to the first one which could be your main window.

If the pop-up window is created by `window.createPopup()` then you will not be able to switch to it - such windows are not supported by Selenium 2. There's some progress in implementing it - see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=27

Comment: Thanks for the anwser i will investigate further

Comment: Well I am using a dialog box, and there arnt very many selenium alternatives out there

Comment: What do you mean by dialog box? Is it JavaScript alert()? Can you post piece of html?

Comment: well i have named the the dialogbox to form1 but i still recieving an error, when doing driver.switchTo().frame("form1") or even driver.switchTo().window("form1")

Comment: It seems that we have to wait when support of popups, alerts and modal dialogs will be implemented

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the id you're searching for is "ButtonCancle".  There's a misspelling there.  Is it possible that you should be looking for "ButtonCancel"?

Comment: nop when trying another button name e.g Accept Address i still get the same error message